# Is it allowed to bump a question by doing an unnecessary edit?

Tags: discussion, questions, edits

Suppose I asked a question and it did not get enough attention for about 1 day. Is it then allowed to do an unnecessary edit to my question so that it appears at the top of the question list?

Comment: Abusing the feature might well lead to backlash. Think twice.

Comment: An unnecessary edit is a bad idea.  If your question isn't getting much attention, then it's quite possible that there might *useful* edits you could make, though.

Comment: Of course, it is. You have some doubts?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Getting attention with edits (you need one every 3-5 minutes on active tags like C#) is a questionable idea.

[Bounties](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) exist for exactly this reason (and should not be a huge problem for one with 1000+ reputation).

Answer (score 75):

Bart and Alexiei are *exactly correct*, and I'd like to add a nuance here...

If you have an idea for a *substantive* edit that will make it easier to get an answer, please never hesitate to do so. The *side benefit* will be the added attention. As long as your edit isn't specifically for the attention, it's fine.

I know you were asking specifically about unnecessary edits here, but I just wanted to also add the above.

Comment: Do you want [Populist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/39/populist) badge? ;)

Comment: @nicael Oooh!!! I think the current voting totals mean I get it!!

Comment: "Awarded 1h ago" Well there it is

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Aha!

Comment: Nuance is for the weak!

Comment: @Bart Well, I *did* stay at a Holiday Inn Express.