# Is there any penalty for bumping up own questions by unnecessary edits?

Tags: discussion, questions

Answers to [*Is it allowed to bump a question by doing an unnecessary edit?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261030/1778421) simply state that reasonable people should not be doing that. But I am just curious about if there is anything ever been done to actually discourage those who decide to ignore the guidelines?

Comment: There was, but it was removed because people kept complaining about it.

Comment: According to [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide), one can only make 5 edits on one's own posts per day, more for high-rep users. The number _might_ be different on SO.

Comment: It only takes an edit every other day or so to stay on the front page in the tags where this behavior annoys me the most.

Comment: If someone is abusing it (like has a page of trivial edits), flag it as Other and let the mods know what's up with that user.

Comment: @Servy Because it was stupid - after ten edits the answer would auto-convert to community wiki and you'd lose all the rep for the answer.  It was a massive disincentive to both continuous improvement of answers *and* keeping older answers up to date.

Comment: @J... You don't lose rep when an answer is converted to CW, you just stop getting rep from *new* votes, and the answers that actually got *meaningful* and *significant* edits enough times to actually trigger it were vanishingly small, to the point that managing those cases manually was not a problem at all.

Comment: @S.L. Barth: That's different. This question is about multiple edits to the *same* post over an indefinite period of time.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If someone makes beyond a certain number of edits on one of their posts, moderators receive an automatic flag from the system. If we determine that these edits are being used to "bump" a post, we have a template message that we can send to warn people to stop doing this.

If the edits continue after that warning, or they've been warned before, we can lock the post and / or suspend the user to stop this.

It used to be that too many edits triggered an automatic wiki conversion, but that had too many side-effects and didn't resolve the problem, so [this was changed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203616/can-we-disable-automatic-community-wiki-conversion-for-answer-edits/228947#228947). Since that change, there haven't been too many cases where we've needed to step in, and even fewer where a gentle warning didn't stop someone from doing this.

Comment: Are these edit thresholds time-sensitive? E.g. is there a difference to the system whether it is being edited several times in one day or once every so often?

Comment: @TylerH - I don't believe so. If I remember correctly, the flag is triggered once X number of edits have accumulated by the author on a post. Don't remember what X is, either, since the flags we see from this aren't all that frequent.

Comment: Cool, thanks. I have a particular post I have updated quite a bit with new info/dates since 2015 I was thinking of, but *most* of those edits have been substantive. I will try to hold off on editing that one unless necessary.

Comment: From my experience, it is after 20 edits.

Comment: @TylerH: Why? If they are good edits, then edit. It's better to have posts that are updated. I think the moderators can handle an unnecessary flag once in a while.

Comment: @TylerH: 20 edits, not time-sensitive.

Comment: Is this policy still in place? I've seen a user make 30 edits to their question in a few hours, and they don't seem to have been blocked from more edits yet.