# Should unnecessary formatting (that serves to draw attention) be considered an antipattern?

Tags: discussion, formatting

I've noticed a pattern recently (though it's probably not new) of answers using formatting to grab attention. For example, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31445046/148423) uses a H1 and a blockquote to make the answer really stand out. Neither is needed for semantics.

Edit: Since the answer has since been edited, here's the revision in question: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/31445046/2

I guess H1 was used because it's the biggest and boldest so it takes up the most screen real-estate. And the blockquote renders with a yellow background which is more attention-grabbing. This isn't a quote from anywhere. It seems to be a case of style over substance.

The answer is good and seems to be upvoted in spite of, not because of, the attention-grabbing. And the author has more than 100k reputation points, so they're not new to the site.

In my book, this counts against an answer as it gives an unfair advantage, hurts readability and is an abuse of formatting semantics. Should such answers be considered problematic and worth an edit? Are they worth a downvote?

Comment: "Are they worth a down-vote?" Not because of the formatting, because we all can fix that formatting with an edit. You're still free to downvote of course, but this case isn't what votes are for. Regarding that H1 formatting: it is imo ok if you have important information, like possible security risk an answer may introduce, but in the linked case, no, that should be edited out.

Comment: Thanks for the perspective. I guess if the answer was edited, the author with 100k would just edit it back.

Comment: Maybe, we don't know. You could also write a comment together with your edit to explain why you've edited. And _if_ that case would end up in an edit war, you're still free to flag that question for moderator attention (but I don't think that would happen).

Comment: Not that it's of much relevance, but that answer's author is a mod himself.

Comment: To @tom and yivi's points, (and speaking as someone who's been on SO for nine years) I would only go and edit another's answer for reasons generally acceptabe to the community. Some of those are obvious, like typos in text or code. I'm asking whether this kind of formatting is considered sufficiently problematic to go and edit a highly-voted answer.

Comment: I try not to over-think it. If I see formatting used where it's not appropriate, I feel is OK to edit it out. Titles for "sections"? OK. Block-quote for high-light? Not OK.

Comment: Very strange that another mod deleted my "this is post is discussed on meta" reminder under the answer. When the community convention is to write such comments so the author can be included in the discussion, when why do mods delete that comment?

Comment: (1) The blockquote is, strictly speaking, an actual quote: the text in it is the title of the question, as written by the question author. While one might argue it is not essential to have that in the answer, I don't think there is enough of a case for outright removing it, so I just edited the answer to make it look more like a normal quote. (2) Given that the main purpose of an "is being discussed on Meta" comment is notifying the OP, and that the OP in this case is a mod, it seems reasonable for him to delete the comment upon seeing it.

Comment: @Tom it was deleted because someone flagged it as "no longer needed". I did see the edits, but I missed your comment. Perhaps the title, as it was in the comment, was a little unnecessary - Lundin's comment hasn't been flagged. Anyways, no harm done.

Comment: @AaronHall thanks for checking in. Hope you don't take this as personal. There's a wider pattern I see in the community that makes the site a bit less ergonomic (for me at least). I just came across your post today (thanks!) and it prompted me to ask this Q.

Comment: @AaronHall "no longer needed" is rather strange, since I wrote that comment (and it got deleted) before both edits happened. Yes, no harm done, but it is strange that someone abused that flagging system.

Comment: Headings are great. Quoting parts of peoples' questions is helpful if it clarifies the connection between the question and the answer. That's especially true if you're answering part of a question and are concerned that someone who didn't read the whole question might not realize that you really are answering it. But H1 inside a blockquote? It's creative, but IMO slightly tacky.

Comment: Sometimes I quote the question in my answer using blockquotes. People may find the answer through search results, and be directed to the answer immediately. Thus, they haven't even read the question otherwise.

Comment: so just because someone's answer is more welcoming and accessible because they took the time to format it better it should be down voted? That answer is very nicely formatted, I was a professional commercial graphic artist back in the day, went to school for 4 years for it and everything, and focused on typography, that answer is very nice visually and nothing about it is **unnecessary** if it makes it easier to see what is going on.  Stupid pedantic critical crap like this is question of the reasons driving reasons I reset my 40K+ account and quit ...

Comment: @JarrodRoberson - did you look at the original version or the version that was edited in response to this question? Here it is. https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/31445046/2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any penalty for bumping up own questions by unnecessary edits?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341341/is-there-any-penalty-for-bumping-up-own-questions-by-unnecessary-edits)

Comment: I don't agree with the dupe. This is about how the answer is styled, not the activity around styling.

Comment: @Joe - all the revisions are fine, their intention is not malicious as the OP suggested in their title. using a single `#` might not be as *tasteful* to some, but there is nothing fundamentally wrong with it, much less any reason to institutionalize down voting answers because of formatting or accused intent with the actual content is accurate and correct. But it is kind of a moot point with the entropy acceleration that is going on now. Pedantically debating using tags as typography is rearranging deck chairs when the site is sinking and veterans are leaving the sinking ship.

Answer (score 17):

Quoting the OP when answering is perfectly fine and often makes the answer easier to read and understand.

However, quoting the *exact title* of the question at the top of an answer doesn't add anything. Everyone reading will already implicitly assume that the question, as stated, is what's being answered... that's kind of the core purpose of the site.

So this is to be regarded as "fluff", for which we already have a policy: [Should I remove 'fluff' when editing questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions). Someone already made an edit to make it stand out less, but I now took the liberty to edit out the whole thing.

Regarding using headlines for different parts of the answer, that's perfectly fine. You can either use

**bold**

or

## headline

Comment: I have several points I take issue with in this answer that I address in my answer. In short: The meta Q&A being cited here are about *questions*, not *answers*, bold is semantically incorrect for a heading, and web design best practices say only use one H1 (meaning answerers shouldn't use them), and I note several value adds for directly quoting the question.

Answer (score 11):

I agree that H1 is too big (semantically), I've been switching to H2's as my largest/top-level heading. But if everyone agrees that it is too large, then this problem could be solved with adjusting the markdown translation - otherwise, why does Stack Overflow make the single `#` heading formatting available?

> This isn't a quote from anywhere.

I was quoting the question. Whenever I quote something word-for-word, I use the blockquote style to ensure the reader knows I am using someone else's words - I don't want to be accused or guilty of plagiarism - and I say who it is unless, through the context, the author isn't immediately clear.

Now the big question at hand:

### Should I quote the title of the question?

I usually quote the relevant part that I am writing a response to.

Titles may evolve. Quoting the exact question explains to the reader the precise question that the answer is answering. It also helps signal to other users if the question's meaning has subtly been changed too much by editors.

It is also helpful to quote the question where other answers embark on tangents to remind the reader what is being asked.

Some might argue that the title is in the window decoration, but it is not repeated in the top of *my* browser (I use a highly customized XFCE desktop).

We may also link directly to the answer, and visitors following such links would find that immediately seeing a short version of question being answered by the post to be very useful.

I also find it helpful to simply remind myself what I'm answering, as I can be forgetful.

So I dispute the assertion, made in another answer, that precisely quoting the question is fluff.

In this very specific case, the answer is very near the question, so I'm inclined to leave it as edited without the quote.

> Should such answers be considered problematic and worth an edit?

I would rather users not do this kind of unnecessary editing, though.

> Are they worth a downvote?

If you don't like how an answer is formatted and want to downvote it because of the formatting, then you may do so.

You can downvote for quite literally any reason so long as it has to do with the post and not the author.

#### Response to another answer

> However, quoting the exact title of the question at the top of an answer doesn't add anything.

I have offered several points of value that it adds.

> So this is to be regarded as "fluff", for which we already have a policy: [Should I remove 'fluff' when editing questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions).

The meta Q&A being cited here are about *questions*, not *answers*.

Further, the answer supports using bold as a heading, which is semantically improper, or H1, which goes against best practices.

#### Response to a comment

> You're one of the few users that do this and while I accept your reasoning it might turn out this is your personal flavor of representing your posts, not one that is followed by the wider community.

I would suggest that community acceptance is represented by votes, not by studying the average style of posts. The average post is suboptimal. Some bottom quantile of posts are so bad that they are deleted.

I tend to write canonical answers to old questions. My answers show up sometimes under very old tangential or even completely wrong posts. I'm trying to use correct formatting to better communicate. A wall of text is not very readable. I prefer short sentences. Short paragraphs. Headings that direct the topic being discussed.

That's what the formatting is for - to communicate. Not to "draw attention."

I have studied communications in the business school - and I have taught that class as well. I'm following communications best practices.

I'm not saying everyone should emulate me.

Maybe more of the better answers should, though.

Comment: You're one of the few users that do this and while I accept your reasoning it might turn out this is your personal flavor of representing your posts, not one that is followed by the wider community.

Comment: "Fluff" in answers is rare, because of the nature of answers, but it certainly includes things like signatures etc. What it boils down to in this case is that nobody else on the site quotes the exact question title with `#headline` in their answers. If the title of the question changes radically, to the point where posted answers are invalid, that should be fixed with a rollback of the question edit. Quoting the OP's question(s) is otherwise fine, I do that too now and then.

Comment: Ultimately usability is a very personal (and diverse) thing, hence my question to the community. Thanks very much for engaging with this, you clearly have sound reasons. Separately, I've seen lots of low-quality answers (like one-liners) that compete with each other for upvotes. Sorry for lumping your answer in with those, in hindsight it isn't very representative of other post that led to my question. If I could track down those others I would have.

Comment: "Should I quote the title of the question" - I feel this usually makes the answer much less useful as a reference post, specifically *because* the question may evolve (so you'd then be quoting something which no longer exists, yet the answer can still be equally applicable), it makes it harder to read and it focuses on the specific details in the question instead of trying to make something more generally useful. I much prefer using "proper" headings or giving a full sentence answer: e.g. instead of ">Should I...? No." say "Do not...".