# Edit question or post new question to attract interest?

Tags: support

Let's say I posted a question five days ago, and it received very little views and no answers.

Assuming I edit a question, will it be displayed as a new question, or will it still be in the five-day queue?

I simply want to change the title, and maybe some of the question, so it looks more approachable.

Comment: One thing you may do is to add a tag if you realise your question lacks tagging and thus visibility. But don't do it to *attract interest*, do it to *improve your question*.

Comment: I think I've seen that question and it look very good to me. You can consider starting a [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) on that question

Comment: @Badda, the question cannot be improved. The question is clear, and the code used runs in Stack Snippets. It's either a lack of interest, or nobody knows.

Comment: Can someone tell me why it's been downvoted three times?

Comment: Down-votes on meta doesn't mean the same thing. They are likely meaning that people don't agree with the idea of editing a question to attract interest.

Comment: I don't understand. People don't agree with the idea of editing **and** people don't agree with the idea of a new question. What exactly should I do then?

Comment: Start a bounty, as said in the answer. A question will stay active as long as people will comment/answer it

Comment: _"It's either a lack of interest, or nobody knows."_ Or, simply, the question has been lost in the flood of other questions. If the question is otherwise perfect, your options are to add a bounty and/or share the question to the world (social media, relevant message boards, etc.).

Comment: People don't agree with editing a question just to bump it. They also don't agree with creating a new question to try and gain interest. This is seen as abusing the system and possibly why you are being downvoted here. Bounties are there for this reason and no they don't guarantee you'll get an answer but they do increase the chance of one

Comment: *the question cannot be improved* The alt text of the image in that question still says "enter image description here". Almost any descriptive text that actually describes the image would be better than that.

Comment: @BSMP, you're right. I'll add a description to the image. I hope it makes a difference.

Answer (score 11):

**Please do not post a new question to attract interest.** This is not how Stack Overflow works.

If you have necessary edits to make to the question, then please make them however be wary about making unnecessary edits. Have a read over [Is it allowed to bump a question by doing an unnecessary edit?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261030/is-it-allowed-to-bump-a-question-by-doing-an-unnecessary-edit). Just be sure to add as much information as you can to your question when you make the edit.

If you want to attract interest you may want to consider adding a [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) to your question.

Comment: If you look at the question, you will see that it cannot be improved. The question is clear, and the code used runs in Stack Snippets. It's either a lack of interest, or nobody knows.

Comment: Then the bounty is the way to go. I haven't judged your question on Stack Overflow. I have only answered the question here. Re-posting a question _may_ result in you being throttled from asking further questions and we don't want that. If you feel you've a good question, place a bounty on it.

Comment: I still don't understand what happens when a question is edited. Does it go back to the top of the tag queue or does it remain in the same spot?

Comment: Yes editing does "bump" the question to the top of the tag queue and for those that sort the tag by _active_ will see this question. Remember however, they will see the post every time it's changed and if they feel you're abusing the system to bump your question you may be downvoted.

Comment: @rbhat: Have a look at the "What happens when I edit a post?" section of the [Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing).